# Virtual Machine Manager wants to inhibit shortcuts - again and again - on Wayland

Tags: fedora, wayland, virt-manager

I've recently reinstalled my workstation with Fedora 27, and since doing so, virt-manager has been doing one strange thing.

Every time I open a VM console and then move the mouse into the window, a dialog appears asking me:

> **Virtual Machine Manager wants to inhibit shortcuts**
>
> You can restore shortcuts by pressing Super+Escape.

[image: virt-manager screenshot]

It doesn't seem to matter whether I click Deny or Allow. In either case, pressing keys such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> are handled by virt-manager, rather than sent to the VM. In that case, for example, instead of deleting a word on the line I'm editing, the window closes.

Before reinstalling my machine, which was also on Fedora 27, I never saw this dialog box.

The only change I can recall making with respect to virt-manager is to add a PolicyKit rule to [allow my user to manage system virtual machines without a password](https://serverfault.com/a/739614/126632):

```
# cat /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/51-org.libvirt.unix.manage.rules 
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
        if (action.id == "org.libvirt.unix.manage" &&
            subject.user == "error") {
                return polkit.Result.YES;
                polkit.log("action=" + action);
                polkit.log("subject=" + subject);
        }
});
```

These are the package versions I have now:

```
# rpm -q libvirt-daemon virt-manager
libvirt-daemon-3.7.0-3.fc27.x86_64
virt-manager-1.4.3-2.fc27.noarch
```

**The other difference is that now I am on Wayland, whereas before I was using X. When I log in with "Gnome on Xorg", the problem goes away.**

How do I prevent this useless dialog from appearing under Wayland, and have command keys such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> be sent to the VM rather than processed by virt-manager?

Comment: wayland is still under heavy development and there may not be a configuration tweak to solve this problem for you.  your best bet for a solution may be to reproduce this with the latest versions, then file a bug with your wayland compositor and/or virt-manager.

Comment: same here! https://askubuntu.com/questions/1000207/key-grabbing-under-wayland-shortcuts-wont-work-in-virt-manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should upgrade/reinstall your workstation with Fedora 30.  The improvements to Wayland in the latest release have fixed that issue.

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1668036

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/merge_requests/382

Comment: Looks like that will fix the problem. I am still curious why this prompt even exists in the first place, though. It seems rather useless.

Answer (score 0):

This is an additional option to resolve this challenge. In addition to John Call's good answer [above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/541440/210877).

If you use Wayland with GNOME, but somehow you can not yet upgrade your Wayland to the latest stable version, a quick and easy temporary workaround is to install this GNOME Extension at https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1619/quiet-shortcuts/